# How to fix long scratch in wood floor?

Tags: repair, flooring, hardwood-floor, scratches

How do I hide a scratch in my hardwood floor? I made the mistake of dragging a piece of furniture and got ahead of myself, and didn’t see that[image] I left a long scratch. I tried to fix a small section using some coconut oil, but that really only made the scratch more noticeable. Any advice on both how to hide the scratch and fix the darker section from the coconut oil? There are real wood floors - white oak. I know nothing about the stain.

The picture of attaching has both the regular scratch and the darker section[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smQog.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried searching here for "scratch wood floor"? There are a number of good answers; I haven't gone through in detail but this is probably a duplicate of one or more of those questions.